# systemd logcheck rule not working

Tags: logging, debian-wheezy, regex, systemd

given is this logcheck rule:

```
^\w{3} [ :[:digit:]]{11} [._[:alnum:]-]+ systemd-logind\[[[:digit:]]+\]: New session [[:digit:]]+ of user [^[:space:]]+\.$
```

and this log entry:

```
Mar 19 09:16:09 horst kernel: [3257039.867032] <38>systemd-logind[193047]: New session 24987 of user icinga.
```

These don't seem to match, unfortunately I cannot find a matching (sic) rule for the <38> thing. And yes, this seems to be a static number.

Comment: I do not understand what you are trying to do. Why not add `<38>` to the regular expression before `systemd-logind`?

Answer (score 0):

## Where the <38> comes from

in [RFC 3164](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3164.txt), the heading *4.1.1 PRI Part* describes the function of <38>. It is the facility and severity of the message combined into one number:

```
facility * 8 + severity = 38
facility = 4 = "AUTH"
severity = 6 = "INFO"
```

This number is *normally* stripped off by the syslog daemon before writing it to a file.

## How to fix the regular expression

The best way to find the problem in this case is to compare the regular expression to the line part by part.
You did not match the `kernel: [123.456]` part:

```
^\w{3} [ :[:digit:]]{11} [._[:alnum:]-]+ kernel: \[[[:digit:] .-]+\] <38>systemd-logind\[[[:digit:]]+\]: New session [[:digit:]]+ of user [^[:space:]]+\.$
```